# how angularjs reference module load dependency

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a main module, that loads `ngRoute` service.

```
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "app.settings"]
```

and my `app.settings` module is not loading `ngRoute` service,

```
angular.module("app.settings", [])
    .config(["$routeProvider", function($routeProvider){
        $routeProvider.when("/settings", { 
            template: "{{message}}", 
            controller:"SettingsController"
        });
}])
```

But I can use `$routeProvider` in this module.

Does angular module loading order not care? Can I load any dependency any module?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The thing is that your `app` module is loading the `ngRoute`, and also is loading your `app.settings` modules, so the dependency is already injected into your Angular application, so there is no need to injected again.

**Does angular module loading order not care?**
The order doesn't matter Angular first resolve the dependencies and then compiles the modules, controllers etc.

```
angular.module("app", ["ngRoute", "app.settings"]
```

Is the same as

```
angular.module("app", ["app.settings", "ngRoute"]
```

However you can run into troubles in some Unit Test scenarios if you only load the module `app.settings` your test will fail. But in the most cases you are going to load the `app` module and all the main modules of your Angular application.

**Can I load any dependency any module?** Short answer, yes.

Long answer: Your `ngRoute` dependency should be loaded in the main module because is something which your `app` module is going to need it to define the basic routing, if the dependency is loaded in several modules is not going to throw any error, in fact **you should add all the dependencies needed by each module because** in large applications **there is no guarantee that the `ngRoute`/`myFactory`/etc  is already loaded.**

**Update to improve readability**